# Interpretation of the Result of Dieharder Battrery of Tests: Very High p-value Result in rgb_lagged_sum Test in Dieharder Results in "WEAK" Assesment

Tags: random-number-generator, pseudo-random-generator, randomness, statistical-test

I'm currently testing the randomness of using SHA-256 in Hash_DRBG mechanism based on [this research](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01763). The parameters used in the testing are the default parameters, except for when the PRNG fails a certain test, the p-sample is doubled in a subsequent test. The result is as follows.

| Test | n-tuple | p-samples | p-value | Assessment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| diehard_birthdays | 0 | 100 | 0.43249977 | PASSED |
| diehard_operm5 | 0 | 100 | 0.60606614 | PASSED |
| diehard_rank_32x32 | 0 | 100 | 0.72622055 | PASSED |
| diehard_rank_6x8 | 0 | 100 | 0.24741913 | PASSED |
| diehard_bitstream | 0 | 100 | 0.93753414 | PASSED |
| diehard_count_1s_stream | 0 | 100 | 0.76684762 | PASSED |
| diehard_count_1s_byte | 0 | 100 | 0.97873412 | PASSED |
| diehard_parking_lot | 0 | 100 | 0.16111731 | PASSED |
| diehard_2dsphere | 2 | 100 | 0.49536684 | PASSED |
| diehard_3dsphere | 3 | 100 | 0.23973302 | PASSED |
| diehard_squeeze | 0 | 100 | 0.67110118 | PASSED |
| diehard_runs | 0 | 100 | 0.99444050 | PASSED |
| diehard_runs | 0 | 100 | 0.70217813 | PASSED |
| diehard_craps | 0 | 100 | 0.56128192 | PASSED |
| diehard_craps | 0 | 100 | 0.57819208 | PASSED |
| marsaglia_tsang_gcd | 0 | 100 | 0.92075700 | PASSED |
| marsaglia_tsang_gcd | 0 | 100 | 0.99119972 | PASSED |
| sts_monobit | 1 | 100 | 0.09297486 | PASSED |
| sts_runs | 2 | 100 | 0.79081331 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 1 | 100 | 0.89838273 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 2 | 100 | 0.78716413 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 3 | 100 | 0.92203605 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 3 | 100 | 0.65570434 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 4 | 100 | 0.19614051 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 4 | 100 | 0.57925551 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 5 | 100 | 0.23663729 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 5 | 100 | 0.90170006 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 6 | 100 | 0.64931499 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 6 | 100 | 0.69010358 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 7 | 100 | 0.42388924 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 7 | 100 | 0.99347778 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 8 | 100 | 0.74742090 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 8 | 100 | 0.44604533 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 9 | 100 | 0.57977435 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 9 | 100 | 0.13159624 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 10 | 100 | 0.38560171 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 10 | 100 | 0.95434782 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 11 | 100 | 0.57229876 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 11 | 100 | 0.15792463 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 12 | 100 | 0.92706928 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 12 | 100 | 0.98019070 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 13 | 100 | 0.84666522 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 13 | 100 | 0.93312452 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 14 | 100 | 0.55365506 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 14 | 100 | 0.79327463 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 15 | 100 | 0.23782749 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 15 | 100 | 0.22002745 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 16 | 100 | 0.66132471 | PASSED |
| sts_serial | 16 | 100 | 0.77182523 | PASSED |
| rgb_bitdist | 1 | 100 | 0.64747038 | PASSED |
| rgb_bitdist | 2 | 100 | 0.51877252 | PASSED |
| rgb_bitdist | 3 | 100 | 0.41006132 | PASSED |
| rgb_bitdist | 4 | 100 | 0.40851961 | PASSED |
| rgb_bitdist | 5 | 100 | 0.59300019 | PASSED |
| rgb_bitdist | 6 | 100 | 0.28861909 | PASSED |
| rgb_bitdist | 7 | 100 | 0.00372080 | WEAK |
| rgb_bitdist | 7 | 200 | 0.15287515 | PASSED |
| rgb_bitdist | 8 | 100 | 0.85025803 | PASSED |
| rgb_bitdist | 9 | 100 | 0.43605146 | PASSED |
| rgb_bitdist | 10 | 100 | 0.83149474 | PASSED |
| rgb_bitdist | 11 | 100 | 0.39785076 | PASSED |
| rgb_bitdist | 12 | 100 | 0.91967414 | PASSED |
| rgb_minimum_distance | 2 | 1000 | 0.17766404 | PASSED |
| rgb_minimum_distance | 3 | 1000 | 0.79247782 | PASSED |
| rgb_minimum_distance | 4 | 1000 | 0.51699768 | PASSED |
| rgb_minimum_distance | 5 | 1000 | 0.24978643 | PASSED |
| rgb_permutations | 2 | 100 | 0.34186729 | PASSED |
| rgb_permutations | 3 | 100 | 0.17690627 | PASSED |
| rgb_permutations | 4 | 100 | 0.32725247 | PASSED |
| rgb_permutations | 5 | 100 | 0.85283344 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 0 | 100 | 0.35023504 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 1 | 100 | 0.73612544 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 2 | 100 | 0.19885141 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 3 | 100 | 0.88639389 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 4 | 100 | 0.71678053 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 5 | 100 | 0.69452785 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 6 | 100 | 0.87311557 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 7 | 100 | 0.57060025 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 8 | 100 | 0.58427119 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 9 | 100 | 0.18178947 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 10 | 100 | 0.24707067 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 11 | 100 | 0.42055800 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 12 | 100 | 0.29616065 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 13 | 100 | 0.29282504 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 14 | 100 | 0.10482720 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 15 | 100 | 0.21482880 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 16 | 100 | 0.30997101 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 17 | 100 | 0.63437543 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 18 | 100 | 0.15671220 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 19 | 100 | 0.31534388 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 20 | 100 | 0.73111917 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 21 | 100 | 0.52711913 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 22 | 100 | 0.45640958 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 23 | 100 | 0.84830587 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 24 | 100 | 0.13624445 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 25 | 100 | 0.74267452 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 26 | 100 | 0.99706185 | WEAK |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 26 | 200 | 0.80227931 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 27 | 100 | 0.06701886 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 28 | 100 | 0.98841011 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 29 | 100 | 0.44516079 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 30 | 100 | 0.19377513 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 31 | 100 | 0.70575626 | PASSED |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 32 | 100 | 0.82280212 | PASSED |
| rgb_kstest_test | 0 | 1000 | 0.04551584 | PASSED |
| dab_bytedistrib | 0 | 1 | 0.39520224 | PASSED |
| dab_dct | 256 | 1 | 0.59555375 | PASSED |
| dab_filltree | 32 | 1 | 0.34799918 | PASSED |
| dab_filltree | 32 | 1 | 0.72922031 | PASSED |
| dab_filltree2 | 0 | 1 | 0.74629061 | PASSED |
| dab_filltree2 | 1 | 1 | 0.72988477 | PASSED |
| dab_monobit2 | 12 | 1 | 0.09431643 | PASSED |

The PRNG, understandably with such a low p-value, fails at the rgb_bitdist with 7 n-tuple. However it also fails rgb_lagged_sum with p-value at 0.99706185. If i understand correctly, that p-value is the result of the final Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. What does this result indicates?

Comment: A most common cause of failure or near failure in Dieharder is too short input. Quoting the manual: _"Note well that file input rands are delivered to the tests on demand, but if the test needs more than are available it simply rewinds the file and cycles through it again, and again, and again as needed. Obviously this significantly reduces the sample space and can lead to completely incorrect results for the p-value histograms unless there are enough rands to run EACH test without repetition (it is harmless to reuse the sequence for different tests). Let the user beware!."_

Comment: Thank you, @fgrieu. I understand how the input length could be a problem, but I don't understand why the assessment comes out as "WEAK" when the p-value is very high. How the generator didn't pass the test despite the p-value observed, rather than why the generator didn't pass per se.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the "P-values and the Null Hypothesis" section of [the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dieharder), p-values are expected to be uniformly distributed on [0,1]. Dieharder makes the very reasonable choice to flag as suspicious p-values that are very close to 0 or to 1.

That's much like when testing for the number of one bits in 1,000,000 outputs of a RNG, getting 500,001 is somewhat suspicious (there is less than one chance out of 417 to be at most 1 off the expected 500,000), more so than getting 501,452 (there is more than one chance out of 271 to be at least 1,452 off).

Here, a p-value $0.99706185$ or higher should occur with probability one out of $\displaystyle\frac1{1-0.99706185}\approx340$, which is quite unexpected for one given test, hence the WEAK. However, given the number of tests, one or two WEAK is not alarming.

Invariably, when a standard statistical test is applied to the output of a correctly implemented, at least half-decent, Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator (including Hash_DRBG), and the test finds an issue, that's a false positive, or a methodology error in applying the test.

Statistical tests applied to CSPRNGs can only catch some gross mistakes (in the implementation of the CSPRNG, or in applying the test). Performing such tests is an exercise in testing, and illustrating experimentally that CSPRNGs pass all tests of randomness. They are not a valid argument of security.

Statistical tests on the output of a RNG do not have access to the structure of the RNG, when (since [Kerckhoffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle)) access to that structure is an hypothesis in evaluating the security of a CSPRNG. Thus such statistical tests can't be valid arguments of security.